# View Messages on SQS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-sqs

I'm fairly new to how AWS does queues through their SQS product.  I'm writing a small tool in javascript on nodejs using the AWS JavaScript SDK to view the messages on a dead letter queue.

My dilemma: how does one copy down all the messages from an SQS queue while meeting these requirements:

1. Messages that are being copied must remain visible at all times (meaning, VisibilityTimeout must always be zero).
2. There can be no duplicates.

Item #2 can be solved easily with a set or similar data structure in my code.  The problem is that when the `VisibilityTimeout` is zero the code receives everything over and over again for all eternity, which I understand... but... but I don't want that!

I'd like to peer into the queue and view its messages without making them unavailable to anyone else consuming from the queue.

Comment: I don't think SQS is designed for #1 requirement. AWS Kinesis can do that: every Kinesis app has its own 'view' of the stream/queue which won't interfere with each other.

Comment: Do you still have a consumer that is processing the DLQ?  Would a viable option be to consume the messages and write them to e DynamoDB table.  That way you can easily query them, the only issue is they would no longer be in the queue.

Comment: Nothing consumes from the DLQ.  I've pondered just marking messages invisible for say 30 seconds or so.  I might end up doing that.  Also, the DynamoDB idea might be a good alternative, too.  Thanks!

Comment: Building on the DynamoDB approach, you could use a scheduled AWS Lambda function to consume the messages from the DLQ and write them to DynamoDB to simplify the overall implementation.